# IF condition in neo4j cypher import script for loading csv

Tags: neo4j

I have a onetime import script .cql written to load data into neo4j using cypher.

We have multiple files ~60 files which i mention in the.cql script. Can I have an if condition on the each load statement which would check if file exists. If it exists then **run** that block of code else **skip** it.

something like this:

```
    if(file1 exists)   // how can i have if statement like this?
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
    "file:///C:/file1"
    AS csvLine 
    CREATE (p:Capability{id:csvLIne.ID,name:csvLine.Name});

    if(file2 exists) // how can i have if statement like this?
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
    "file:///C:/file2"
    AS csvLine 
    CREATE (p:Position{id:csvLIne.ID,name:csvLine.Name});

    if(file3 exists)
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
    "file:///C:/file3"
    AS csvLine 
    CREATE (p:busProc{id:csvLIne.ID,name:csvLine.Name});

    if(file4 exists)
    LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
    "file:///C:/file4"
    AS csvLine 
    CREATE (p:Role{id:csvLIne.ID,name:csvLine.Name});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cypher does not provide a way to test for file existence, so it is not possible to do what you propose.

Since you seem to be running on Windows, you could write a  batch file that tested for the existence of each file and ran the appropriate Cypher script for each one that is found.

Comment: Even I thought of the same option as you have suggested. Just wanted to have second opinion that it cannot be done using cypher